# Angular: Mat-tab activate tabe

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know that I can set the selected tab in a `mat-tab-group` with `[selectedIndex]="0"`. This is a redundant way to set it because the first tab is selected anyway.

Nevertheless the tab is not activated when opened first. One could easily see it when you place a `matBadge` on the tab. The badge is clearly rendered as inactive - which could be seen as well in the fonts by itself.

[image: Inactive badge]

But when I actively click on the first tab it is rendered properly
[image: Activated tab]

Is there a way to fix it (or is it a bug)? A sample code could be found on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y4kyje?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

This issue a css issue. It can be fixed by adding .mat-tab-label-active class in css file

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

if its not working try

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-label-active {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Adding it to the `css` doesn`t have any kind of effect. Although I see that settng it in the browser directly has an effect. I guess Angular does not apply it properly.

Comment: see whether that class is getting applied in browser, else use /deep/

Comment: Yeah it works. But `/deep/` is deprecated - see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: but that's the only solution I found for that

Comment: Well, yeah... Therefore I filled a bug (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17124)

Comment: @LeO but when I checked in stackblitz even without /deep/ its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199623/discussion-between-leo-and-anil-kumar-reddy-a).